# issues sorting an array alphabetically

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm currently attempting to sort an array of countries alphabetically with their population, but I'm having an issue sorting it, as one of the countries from the end is placed in the beginning of the array, messing up the sort. Other than that it works. Lets say the array has these values = "Afghanistan","Brazil","Bosnia-And-Herzegovina","Zambia","Turkey".

this is the code I have for the sort:

```
int i;
int j;
String temp;


for(i=0;i<length;i++){
  for(j=1;j<length;j++){
    if(countryList[i].compareToIgnoreCase(countryList[j])<0)
    {
      temp=countryList[i];
      countryList[i]=countryList[j];
      countryList[j]=temp;
    }
  }    //
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `Arrays.sort(countryList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`?

Comment: If you wrap countries you can make them compareable and then compare on more than only the name, and it will be sortable using arrays sort method

Comment: @shmosel I have to sort another array depending on how the country array is sorted. is there a way I can use array.sort and keep the country's population with it. (I didn't add the population to the code as I only have an issue with the country list sort)

Comment: You should make a single class to encapsulate country name and population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as already mentioned, the inner for loop. `j` has to be set to `i + 1`.

There's also another problem: Your comparison is the wrong way. This sorts in ascending alphabetical order:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
        if (countryList[i].compareToIgnoreCase(countryList[j]) > 0) { // >0 instead of <0
            temp = countryList[i];
            countryList[i] = countryList[j];
            countryList[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

But since insertion sort is comparatively slow, I suggest you to use `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: also problem with condition at inner loop it should be `j < length-1` because `j = i+1` and it will be out of bound at last index of i.

Comment: sorry ! I confused it should be `i < length -1` since  ` j = i+1` so no need to go over last index of  `i`  when comparing each others

Answer (score 1):

the problem in for loop condition it should be :

```
for(i=0;i<length-1;i++)
  for(j=i+1;j<length;j++)
```

at the outter loop you should skip the last index of the array because you will compare it with `i+1` index at inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are not implementing the bubble sort correctly. You iterate once from index 0 but it's possible (if the element which should be first is actually last) that you will need to do it n times from index 0 to get the element to the start. The correct implementation should be:

```
boolean swapped = false;
do {
    for each element
        if needs to swap 
            swap
            swapped = true
} while (swapped);
```

Comment: It's not bubble sort. It's insertion sort

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is looking backwards. Change `1` to `i+1` in

```
for(j=1;j<length;j++){
```

Comment: right also the condition should be ` j  <  length-1`  because j = i+1 and it will be out of bound at last index

Comment: @MohammadOghli Uh... no.

Comment: sorry ! I confused it should be `i < length -1` since  `  j = i+1 ` so no need to go over last index of  `i`  when comparing each others

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the second for loop:

```
for(j=1;j<length;j++){
```

Think about it—let's say we're on the fourth iteration, so `i = 3`. Despite `i`'s value, you're starting `j` at 1. Therefore, `j` is less than `i`. This means that you're going to end up reversing results that have previously been correctly sorted. Change it to the following:

```
for(j=i+1;j<length;j++){
```

Now, `j` will always be greater than `i`.

EDIT - See @sprinter 's answer to make sure your implementation actually is correct.